# undefined reference to uncompress zlib android jni

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, zlib

I'm using Zlib library on Android JNI but I'm facing this issue when I build :

```
undefined reference to uncompress
```

I included `zlib.h` & `zconf.h` and here is my CMakeList.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

add_library(core SHARED
        foo1.c
        foo2.c)

# Include libraries needed for core lib
target_link_libraries(core
                  android
                  zlib)
```

Can anyone please tell me what's going on? Thank you !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Resolved by including `z` in `target_link_libraries` in `CMakeList`

It's like this now :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

add_library(core SHARED
    foo1.c
    foo2.c)

# Include libraries needed for core lib
target_link_libraries(core
                     android
                     z)
```